# IE8 border and margin issue

Tags: html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have a styling issue on our company's intranet that I can't figure out. It only happens with IE8 or lower. IE 9/10, FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera are all OK.

The issue is a border and paddings are appearing even though I've used `border:none;`, `margin:0!important;` and `padding:0!important;` and it's pushing the content inside over to the right and causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear.

[image: example]

This is where it gets confusing...
Our intranet (asp) has the "panels" that you can see in the screenshot above.  There is a "Custom HTML" panel that will allow me to insert HTML into the SQL database cell for that panel, but to view a complex html, it's best to store a file.html page and pull it into the panel using an iframe.  I can supply the iframe reference and the css using in my file.html...  which one is the most likely culprit?

**iframe reference in SQL database:**

```
{top|Members,Forum,HTML($$Summit 2013 Information$$<iframe src="http://www.myexternalsource/WORKING_FOLDER/Summit2013/Summit2013.html" width="768" height="1926" style="border:none!important; margin:0px!important; padding:0px!important;"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.<br /><br /><a href="http://www.myexternalsource/WORKING_FOLDER/Summit2013/Summit2013.html" target="_blank">Click here to open in a new window</a></p></iframe>)}{middleLeft|}{middleRight|}{bottom|}{hidden|Announcements,Items,Tasks,Collections,WhatsOn,Activity,RSS,QuoteOfDay,Absentee}
```

**Summit2013.html with irrelevant styles and html removed**

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">
#iframe-wrapper {
    display: block;
    width:760px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
...
</style>
</head>

<body style="margin:5px 0 0 7px !important;">
...
```

Comment: IE8 throws itself into compatibility mode by default for intranet sites. Is that the case here?

Comment: That isn't the case.  It's actually just a private website but the staff call it our intranet.    That said... the dev's who built it have some strange ideas and my IE browser (since 9, has always had to use compatibility mode).
I think (I could be wrong) that the issue is more of a IE CSS rule...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe frameborder="0" ...></iframe>
```

Margins IIRC you can define in the inner page.

Comment: Perfect!  thank you so much.  I spent ages in IE's developer tools trying to nut this one out.